# Is there a new way to undo and redo in the new version of intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I just update my Intellij IDE to 2023 version and i can't use the short key for undo and Redo Ctrl Z and Ctrl Y.

I have tried everything possible and nothing seems to work. can anyone with aid me in sorting this stubborn issue.

Answer (score 3):

IIRC, IntelliJ standard keyboard shortcut for redo is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, so what probably happened is you remapped the shortcut at some point and it just slipped your mind.

The settings window can be found under File > Settings. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> should work if the shortcut hasn't been changed. In the settings window you should find Keymap under the Appearance & Behavior settings list.

Go to:

- File menu
- Settings menu item
- Appearance and Behavior
- Keymap

Conveniently, you can just select some other IDE's mappings to emulate, like VisualStudio, which adheres to Windows UI guidelines so you can have the familiar <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> mappings.

[Official guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html).